# Black Bodies, why is $\nu_{max}\neq {c}/\lambda_{max}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, thermal-radiation, wavelength

I am trying to find Wien's law from Planck's equation but instead of $\lambda$ I am finding frequency.

I found it:

$$\nu_{max} = \frac{(2.82)k_bT}{h}.$$

The following question asks: Why $\nu_{max}\neq {c}/\lambda_{max}$?

I cannot use $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ to turn Wien's law into frequency:
$$\lambda_{max}=\frac{b}{T},$$
where $b$ is Wien's displacement constant.

**EDIT**

[image: questions] **The question I am wondering about is b)**

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law#Derivation_from_Planck.27s_Law) help?

Comment: Yes that does, what do you think my teacher is saying then? I will add the question to the above question.

Comment: Planck's function is *per (unit) wavelength* (or frequency, depending on its form). You have to think a $d \nu$ or $d \lambda$ after it. Derived formulas such as Wien's law need to incorporate this when switching between frequency and wavelength, even if the frequency or wavelength is fixed (at $\nu_{max}$ / $\lambda_{max}$).